# Extract information from dictionary.description?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, struct, swift2

I have a quiz app that is based on a structure containing a Question and Answer components. Users can flick through the questions. Is done by just selecting a new question from my questions structure and displaying it on the screen.

I want to have it where the user can save specific questions if they wish.
These saved questions will be displayed in a different view controller called the Saved view controller.

The save UIAction creates a dictionary of the current question and answer seen on screen.

The save UIAction then appends the current question and answer to an array in a Global structure in the Saved view controller. This is done by accessing the dictionary.description.

The save UIAction then saves what has been put into the array in the Saved view controller by using NSUserDefaults.

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

  //Creating dictionary of current Question and Answer
  let dic = ["Question": Questions[qNumber].question, "Answer": Questions[qNumber].answers]

  //appending the selected question to the likedArray in the saved view controller
  Globals.likedArray.append(dic.description) 

   //saving what has been entered into the likedArray for key "saved array"
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Globals.likedArray, forKey: "SavedArray")

}
```

My problem is that when I access the save question and answer in my saved view controller and display it onscreen, it comes out with extra brackets and is not just the question and answer text.

I believe this is because I have saved it as a dictionary.description. Is there a way that I can extract the information and just have it as text the of the questions and answers?

Or is there a way I can put the information into another structure. As I want the possibility to save multiple questions an display them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've already reached the correct conclusion, you don't want to store `dic.description`. (The description method is only there to give you an easy way to print the value of an object or value for the end user.)

You want `Globals.likedArray.append(dic)`.

However, that may not compile as is, depending on the type of `Globals.likedArray`. If you make the type `[[String:String]]` (array of dictionaries with String keys and values), that should help.

There are other things we could improve in this code, but let's make some progress towards your end goal first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. I been pulling my hair out all day with this one. I have set the likeArray to `[[String:String]]` doing this: `static var likedArray: [String!] = [""]`. It has been to no avail though. Even if i set the append to `Globals.likedArray.append(String(dic))`. Very stuck on this problem :(

Comment: From the code in your comment, it looks like you didn't update the type. Try: `static var likedArray: [[String: String]] = []` and `Globals.likedArray.append(dic)`

Comment: Cool I changed it to `static var likedArray: [[String: String]] = []` but then an error comes up saying "cannot convert value of type [String: String!] to excepected argument type [String: String]" for the line of code `Globals.likedArray.append(dic)`

Comment: Progress! If you change the type of `likedArray` to `[[String: String!]]` that should get you past the compiler error. (Longer term, you generally want to avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals where you can because they will be a source of bugs.)

Comment: Thanks for the positivity man :) yea  i did it there and it will save the dic value fine now. However when try to show it in the new view controller it is still coming up with extra brackets and stuff. such as `Optional((
        {
        Answer = "There are 32 counties";
        Question = "How many counties are in Ireland?";
    }
))` I dont know where the optional text and all the extra brackets are coming from.

Comment: Do you want to ask a new question for the issue with the new view controller?

Comment: Yea Il do that now il just have to try sort thes last little bits up. thanks man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133765/discussion-between-pete800-and-dave-weston).

Comment: I'll come back to your second question later tonight. I need to be at a computer to type it all out.